# Setting profile directories on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: environment-variables

Have made `~/.bash_profile` in my home directory, that calls the file `linge-profile.rc`. Have installed the latest version of Tex Live in `${HOME}/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux`.  I put my settings in the file `${HOME}/Opstk/bin/gun-1.0/linge/linge-profile.rc`, which I source from `~/.bash_profile`.

Here is the contents of `~/.bash_profile`.

```
gun_path="${HOME}/Opstk/bin/gun-1.0"
source ${gun_path}/linge/linge-profile.rc

And the contents of linge-profile.rc being

#!/bin/bash

linge-texlive-paths ()
{
  local -r tldir="${HOME}/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022"
  PATH=${tldir}/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}
  MANPATH=${tldir}/texmf-dist/doc/man:${MANPATH}
  INFOPATH=${tldir}/texmf-dist/doc/info:${INFOPATH}

  export PATH
  export MANPATH
  export INFOPATH
}

linge-texlive-paths
```

But, when I do `echo $PATH`, the directory `${tldir}/bin/x86_64-linux` is not there. I also have a `.profile` file. I am using `Ubuntu 18.04`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but `${tldir}/bin/x86_64-linux` will never be literally there:  the variable will be substututed. Edit your question and indicate what you expect to see and what you currently see. Note that if you have a .bash_profile that .profile is not used.

Comment: `${tldir}` is `${HOME}/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022`.  I have installed Tex Live there.